# How to change keyboard backlight color from blue to white in Dell G3 15 laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard, colors, backlight, dell-g3

I recently bought [Dell G3 15](https://www.flipkart.com/dell-g3-core-i5-9th-gen-8-gb-512-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-4-graphics-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1650-3590-g3-15-3590-gaming-laptop/p/itm04ad795261c5c?pid=COMFRHFBFMNHVYE9&lid=LSTCOMFRHFBFMNHVYE9NMRHNO) Laptop from flipkart. The specifications says RGB Backlit Keyboard. But by default, the color is blue. How can I change the color to white? I couldn't find anything in settings. I also checked in BIOS, where there was option to change the duration of lighting, but no option to change the color.

Note: I tried <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it didn't work :(

Comment: What is the model number of the laptop?

Comment: "Press <FN> + <C> keys to cycle through the available backlight colors." Does this work?

Comment: <FN>+C doesn't work

Comment: Model no: G3 15 3590

Comment: Apparently not possible on some G3 models.

Comment: Yes. I read about that. But Flipkart page (link in question) says this has RGB backlit keyboard

Answer (score 2):

On the [drivers](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-ca/product-support/product/g-series-15-3590-laptop/drivers) page for your laptop, they list the "Alienware Command Center Application" under the "Application" category, the description says:

> This package contains the Alienware Command Center application. The package includes Main Dashboard, Games Library, Game Profile Manager, **AlienFX Lighting Manager** (AlienFX compatible systems and peripherals only), Macro Manager (Supported peripherals and systems only). The Alienware Command Center (AWCC) is software that integrates applications in to a single interface that is designed to control features of your Alienware system.

Once you install this you should be able to adjust your lighting settings.

Comment: I tried this. But when I open Alienware command center, I get a warning saying 'No supported AlienFX devices were detected'

Answer (score 0):

If you open Dell Update, you can run the optional update to install a compatible version of the Alienware control center, and you can control the keyboard RGB from there.